# Face Features Detection Using OpenCV Haar-cascades

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier, eye-detection

I am using `Java` with `OpenCV` Library to detect `Face`,`Eyes` and `Mouth` using `Laptop Camera`.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Capture Video Frames using `VideoCapture` object.
2. Detect `Face` using `Haar-Cascades`.
3. Divide the `Face` region into `Top` Region and `Bottom` Region.
4. Search for `Eyes` inside `Top` region.
5. Search for `Mouth` inside `Bottom` region.

**Problem I am facing:**

- At first Video is running normally and suddenly it becomes slower.

**Main Questions:**

1. Do Higher Cameras' Resolutions work better for Haar-Cascades?
2. Do I have to capture Video Frames in a certain scale? for example `(100px X100px)`?
3. Do `Haar-Cascades` work better in `Gray-scale` Images?
4. Does different lighting conditions make difference?
5. What does the method `detectMultiScale(params)` exactly do?
6. If I want to go for further analysis for `Eye Blinking`, `Eye Closure Duration`, `Mouth Yawning`, `Head Nodding` and `Head Orientation` to Detect Fatigue (Drowsiness) By Using `Support Vector Machine`, any advices?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Check out this: [https://github.com/aashish-bth/Drowsiness-Detection-System](https://github.com/aashish-bth/Drowsiness-Detection-System)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [article](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html), would give you an overview of the things going under the hood, I would highly recommend to read the article.

> Do Higher Cameras' Resolutions work better for Haar-Cascades?

Not necessarily, the [`cascade.detectMultiScale`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) has params to adjust for various input width, height scenarios, like `minSize` and `maxSize`, These are optional params However, But you can tweak these to get robust predictions if you have control over the input image size. If you set the `minSize` to smaller value and ignore `maxSize` then it will work for smaller and high res images as well, but the performance would suffer. Also if you imagine now, How come there is no differnce between High-res and low-res images then you should consider that the `cascade.detectMultiScale` internally scales the images to lower resolutions for performance boost, that is why defining the `maxSize` and `minSize` is important to avoid any unnecessary iterations.

> Do I have to capture Video Frames in a certain scale? for example
>   (100px X100px)

This mainly depends upon the params you pass to the `cascade.detectMultiScale`. Personally I guess that `100 x 100` would be too small for smaller face detection in the frame as some features would be completely lost while resizing the frame to smaller dimensions, and the `cascade.detectMultiScale` is highly dependent upon the gradients or features in the input image.

But if the input frame only has face as a major part, and there are no other smaller faces dangling behind then you may use `100 X 100`. I have tested some sample faces of size `100 x 100` and it worked pretty well. And if this is not the case then `300 - 400` px width should work good. However you would need to tune the params in order to achieve accuracy.

> Do Haar-Cascades work better in Gray-scale Images?

They work only in gray-scale images.

In the [article](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html), if you read the first part, you will come to know that it face detection is comprised of detecting many binary patterns in the image, This basically comes from the [ViolaJones](http://wearables.cc.gatech.edu/paper_of_week/viola01rapid.pdf), paper which is the basic of this algorithm.

> Does different lighting conditions make difference?

May be in some cases, largely Haar-features are lighting invariant.

If you are considering **different lighting** conditions as taking images under green or red light, then it may not affect the detection, The haar-features (since dependent on gray-scale) are independent of the RGB color of input image. The detection mainly depends upon the gradients/features in the input image. So as far as there are enough gradient differences in the input image such as eye-brow has lower intensity than fore-head, etc. it will work fine.

But consider a case when input image has back-light or very low ambient light, In that case it may be possible that some prominent features are not found, which may result in face not detected.

> What does the method detectMultiScale(params) exactly do?

I guess, if you have read the [`article`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html), by this time, then you must be knowing it well.

> If I want to go for further analysis for Eye Blinking, Eye Closure
>   Duration, Mouth Yawning, Head Nodding and Head Orientation to Detect
>   Fatigue (Drowsiness) By Using Support Vector Machine, any advices?

No, I won't suggest you to perform these type of gesture detection with SVM, as it would be extremely slow to run 10 different cascades to conclude current facial state, However I would recommend you to use some Facial Landmark Detection Framework, such as [Dlib](http://dlib.net/face_detection_ex.cpp.html), You may search for some other frameworks as well, because the model size of dlib is nearly 100MB and it may not suit your needs i f you want to port it to mobile device. So the key is ** Facial Landmark Detection **, once you get the full face labelled, you can draw conclusions like if the mouth if open or the eyes are blinking, and it works in Real-time, so your video processing won't suffer much.